# How to define rpcbind portmapper ports range to comply with a firewall allowed range

Tags: firewall

Having an rpc server running but rpcbind portmapper maps ports out of range allowed by firewall.

Already tried to change ip_local_port_range but looks like it is ignored.

Comment: it is not rpcbind role in setting specific ports range, it is the service server that has to publish the proper port

Answer (score 0):

If the service server is subscribing with RPC_ANYSOCK a random port will provided, need to change the rpc server to pick a specific.

rpcbind is just publishing what the server is subscribing